# How to locate and click element inside list?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am very new to webdriver, and got stuck on below.

I want to click highlighted href ([Volunteering](/uservol/application/overview)), and i am not able to do it.

```
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse full-upper-navbar">
<div class="tabs primary-tabs col-sm-11">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navigation">
<li class="selected active home icon">
<li>
<li>
<li>
**<a href="/uservol/application/overview">Volunteering</a>**
</li>
```

I have used below things -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("..//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/uservol/application/overview']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Volunteering")).click();
```

nothing is working out for me, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working"? what exactly is happening?

Comment: I am getting this exception  -Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'Kapils-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.0.0.14', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: Is this html inside `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: no,it is not inside iframe

Answer (score 0):

It might be timing issue. Try using explicit wait to wait for the element to be visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a")));
element.click();
```